# date format is not seperated when fetching from database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have a table named as item_request and it has twofields named as projectmanager and createddate which has the Timestamp format as 2012-09-11 17:46:25.

Now i want to call these two fields in another form which count the user entry between 2 different dates.and the date field is fetched from the timestamp.with this form i m sending the value through datetime picker having the format 10-12-2012 but the value in databse is in different format and the value i m sending is in diffferent format.how is it possible plzzz help me guys.

Here is the code for my form:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
if(!isset($_SESSION[username]))
header("location: index.php");
if(isset($_POST[submit]))
{
$projectmanager=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['projectmanager']);
$date=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$dateexp = explode("-",$date);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($dateexp[0]."/".$dateexp[1]."/".$dateexp[2]);


$date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date1']);
$dateexp1 = explode("-",$date1);
$date1 = mysql_real_escape_string($dateexp1[0]."/".$dateexp1[1]."/".$dateexp1[2]);

echo $queryuser= "select * from  item_request where projectmanager=$projectmanager AND (requireddate>=$date AND requireddate<=$date1)";

}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Project Managers Registrarion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/datetimepicker.js">

//Date Time Picker script- by TengYong Ng of http://www.rainforestnet.com
//Script featured on JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
//For this script, visit http://www.javascriptkit.com

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="images/cherry-new.jpg" width="79" height="93" /></a> 
    <!-- end .header --></div>
<?php include("rightMenu.php");?>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>PR Count</h1>
    <div style="padding:10px 0px; text-align:center; color:#990000;">
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" name="loginform">


<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
  <td>Project Managers</td>
           <td><select name="projectmanager" style="width:145px;" id="projectmanager" onChange="showUser(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id)">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <?php $queryuser= "select * from  projectmanagers";
              $fetuser1user = mysql_query($queryuser);
              while($fetuser = mysql_fetch_array($fetuser1user)){
        ?>
               <option id="<?php echo $fetuser['id']?>" value="<?php echo $fetuser['id']?>"><?php echo $fetuser['projectmanager']?></option>
               <?php }
        ?>
             </select></td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date From</td>
    <td>
      <input id="date" type="text" size="20" name="date"  /><a href="javascript:NewCal('date','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date To</td>
    <td>
      <input id="date1" type="text" size="20" name="date1"><a href="javascript:NewCal('date1','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return formvalidate();"/>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>


       <table width="100%" border="1"><tr>
                <td width="18%" valign="middle" class="tableheading">PI.No.</td>
                <td width="18%" valign="middle" class="tableheading">Project Manager</td>
                <td width="18%" valign="middle" class="tableheading">Date Created</td>
                <td width="15%" valign="middle" class="tableheading">Action</td>
                </tr>
                 <?php 
                 // to print the records
                $select = "select * from item_request";
                $query1 = mysql_query($select);  
                 while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){ ?>

                <tr>
                <td class="tabletext"><?php echo $value[id];?></td>
                <td class="tabletext"><?php echo $value[projectmanager];?></td>
                <td class="tabletext"><?php echo $value[datefrom];?></td>               
                <td class="tabletext"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?id=<?php echo $value[id];?>&cmd=edit"><img src="images/edit.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" title="Edit" /></a>
               <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?id=<?php  echo $value[id];?>&cmd=delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <?php  echo $value[projectmanager];?>?')"><img src="images/deleteBtn.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" title="Edit" /></a></td>
              </tr><?php }?>
                </table>
    </form>


    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <?php include("footer.php");?>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a way to convert a date from MM-DD-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: Or, sorry, MM-DD-YYYY H:M:S to DD-MM-YYYY H:M:S?

Comment: no dude i have the date in the timestamp format in my table as 2012-09-11 17:46:25. and i want to fetch this value in another page which shows the records betweeen two diffrent dates. so i make a form and in it i have a date time picker as shown above which send the request in the format 10-12-1988.
so the timestamp value and my value is not matching atall.how can i achieve it plzzz help me.

Comment: So you are wanting the date in the form to be converted to the same format as that in your database? Is what you've given there '10-12-1988' in DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY format?

Comment: in databse i have a date value having time and the value i m sending is have only date so how can i match it.

Comment: basicaly in databse the value of date is timestamp which have date and time and from my new form im sending the value in only date thats why both date are not matching.

Comment: It looks to me like the date in your form is obtained using jQuery, meaning this isn't a PHP issue. Your jQuery needs to change to grab the H:M:S as well as the DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: yes bro as i mentioned that i m using the date-time-picker from javascript.

Comment: thnks for ur help bro........but it still not working as  i want

Comment: I've updated my answer, did you see the edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this function call...

```
javascript:NewCal('date','ddmmyyyy');
```

with this one...

```
javascript:NewCal('date','ddmmyyyy',true,24);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thnks a lot bro.it works for me....thnks a ton for your help.....:) god blesss u alwys..:)